# How can I retrieve the center of a rotated ellipse from a pyqtgraph EllipseROI?

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I would like to find the center of an ellipse created using the pyqtgraph EllipseROI, generated using the following command:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
...
ellipse = pg.EllipseROI(pos = [200, 200], size=125, pen='r', movable=True)
```

Once a user moves and rotates the ellipse, some information can be retrieved from the handles to determine the new position:

```
x0=ellipse.pos().x()
y0=ellipse.pos().y()
width=ellipse.size()[0]
height=ellipse.size()[1]
angle=ellipse.angle()
```

It looks like the width and height values correspond to the rectangular region surrounding the **non-rotated** ellipse:

[image: Non-Rotated Ellipse]
[image: Rotated Ellipse]

In the above images, the black pixels represent the following points (from lower left, proceeding counter-clockwise):

1. [x0, y0]
2. [x0+width, y0]
3. [x0+width, y0+height]
4. [x0, y0+height]

The center for the ellipse with angle=0 is simply [x0+width/2, y0+height/2]. For a rotated ellipse, I can find the center by rotating the center of the ellipse corresponding to angle=0 about the point [x0, y0]:

```
import numpy as np
...
center_x0 = x0+width/2.0
center_y0 = y0+height/2.0
center_x = x0 + np.cos(np.radians(angle)) * (center_x0 - x0) - np.sin(np.radians(angle)) * (x0 - center_x0)
center_y = y0 + np.sin(np.radians(angle)) * (center_x0 - x0) + np.cos(np.radians(angle)) * (center_y - y0)
```

Am I missing a simple solution to quickly retrieve the center position from the EllipseROI (or any pyqtgraph ROI) that does not first require retrieving the bounding box points of an non-rotated ROI and then rotating their center? I would like to minimize the delay between when the user adjusts the ROI and subsequent displays in the viewbox (that rely on the center point), and the method I am currently using seems like an inefficient way to calculate the center.